# remove one index from a muli-index dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, multi-index

in a python dataframe, having 2 indexes(multi index). How to remove one of the index?
if trying to remove the first index(0-5)

```
        MUL1  MUL2
0   a     1     2
1   b     2     4
2   c     3     6
3   d     4     8
4   e     5    10
5   f     6    12
```

Comment: `pandas.DataFrame.reset_index()` You havent tried this?

Answer (score 0):

```
df = df.reset_index()
df.drop('index_0',inplace=True)
df = df.set_index('index_1')
```

I think this will work for you.
P.S. index_0 and index_1 are the new names of the columns that will be added after resetting the index.